# Two html tables in sync by ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need your help.
I have two tables side by side that I want to sync by ID.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table id="table1" border=1 style="float:left;">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>name</th>
                <th>ID</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Emmanuel</td>
                <td>17321</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Stewart</td>
                <td>94003</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Tana</td>
                <td>44041</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <table id="table2" border=1 style="display: inline-block;">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>score</th>
                <th>ID</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>44041</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>89</td>
                <td>17321</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>25</td>
                <td>94003</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see the tables are unordered, and I want to order them:
http://jsfiddle.net/9jzb1qwg/

This is my approach in jQuery:

```
var rows = [];
$('#table1 tbody tr td:nth-child(2)').each(function () {
    var value = $(this).text();
    var r = $('#table2 tbody tr:has(td:last:contains("' + value + '"))')[0];
    rows.push(r);
});
$('#table2').children("tbody").html(rows);
```

This works fine, but the performance in tables with more columns and more records, runs very slow...
Is there any way to make it faster?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: logic in code shown makes no sense ... there is no sorting done by it and using `contains` to find a parent of a known element is expensive search

Comment: Yeah I agree with @charlietfl

Comment: try deleting pushed rows from 2nd table in each function so it doesnt have to look through the pushed ones again

Comment: I didn't mention that I already have a function to sorting the table1, and this method (very slow btw) is executed after table1 is ordered by other column than ID, so I need to keep in sync the table2 based on ID columns.

Comment: Maybe it can be accomplished by others methods/techniques, but I didn't find anything out there that help in this point. Any tip would be greatly appreciated!